# Full screen quad in the HLSL Directx 11

Tags: directx11

I want to create a full screen Triangle/Quad so I can blur the box that is the quad I made. I want to do this in the vertex buffer. I tried this code:

```
    struct VSQuadOut {
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 uv: TEXCOORD;
};

// outputs a full screen triangle with screen-space coordinates
// input: three empty vertices
VSQuadOut VSQuad( uint vertexID : SV_VertexID ){
    VSQuadOut result;
    result.uv = float2((vertexID << 1) & 2, vertexID & 2);
    result.position = float4(result.uv * float2(2.0f, -2.0f) + float2(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f);
    return result;
}
```

I want something like this
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to know how to do the blur shader, or just how to do the quad?

Answer (score 2):

That is my blur shader, it does a simple gaussian blur first in x direction. Then changing rendertarget to be the texture, and render in y direction to the final rendertarget.

```
//////////////////////////
//       OUTPUT

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH     : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex      : TEXCOORD;
};

//////////////////////////
//     Screen Quad

VertexOut VS(uint id : SV_VertexId)
{
    VertexOut vout;
    vout.Tex = float2(id % 2, (id % 4) >> 1);
    vout.PosH = float4((vout.Tex.x - 0.5f) * 2, -(vout.Tex.y - 0.5f) * 2, 0, 1);
    return vout;
}

//////////////////////////
//        Blur
float pixelOffset[7] = 
{
    -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3
};

float blurFactor[7] =
{
    1, 3, 5, 9, 5, 3, 1
};

float4 PS_BlurX(VertexOut pin) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 sum = float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    [unroll]
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        float4 col = txBlur.Sample(sampleLinear, pin.Tex + float2(pixelOffset[i], 0));
        sum += col * blurFactor[i];
    }
    return sum / 27;
}

float4 PS_BlurY(VertexOut pin) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 sum = float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    [unroll]
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        float4 col = txBlur.Sample(sampleLinear, pin.Tex + float2(0, pixelOffset[i]));
        sum += col * blurFactor[i];
    }
    return sum / 27;
}

//////////////////////////
//      TECHNIQUES

technique11 BlurTech
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_5_0, VS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, PS_BlurX()));
        SetDepthStencilState(noDepth, 0);
        SetRasterizerState(0);
    }

    pass P1
    {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_5_0, VS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, PS_BlurY()));
        SetDepthStencilState(noDepth, 0);
        SetRasterizerState(0);
    }
};
```

And here is the source code:

```
//render screen quads
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(NULL);

    //set viewport
    pd3dImmediateContext->RSSetViewports(1, &g_Viewport.Blur);

    //blur x
    pd3dImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_RTV.BlurTemp, NULL);
    BlurShader::txBlur->SetResource(g_SRV.Blur);
    BlurShader::blurTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->Apply(0, pd3dImmediateContext);
    pd3dImmediateContext->Draw(4, 0);

    //free shader resource
    BlurShader::txBlur->SetResource(0);
    BlurShader::blurTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->Apply(0, pd3dImmediateContext);

    //blur y
    pd3dImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_RTV.Blur, NULL);
    BlurShader::txBlur->SetResource(g_SRV.BlurTemp);
    BlurShader::blurTech->GetPassByIndex(1)->Apply(0, pd3dImmediateContext);
    pd3dImmediateContext->Draw(4, 0);

    //free shader resource
    BlurShader::txBlur->SetResource(0);
    BlurShader::blurTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->Apply(0, pd3dImmediateContext);
```